# Swagger doesn't hide readOnly fields in request docs

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

Previously, given a field in an object, in order to hide it from the swagger doc i.e. make it readonly, you could use the following:

```
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
public String someField;
```

This would make the field readonly, thus hidden in create/edit docs, but it would still be visible in the response body docs.

Now moving from `@ApiModelProperty` to `@Schema` I was expecting that it would work in the same way

```
@Schema(readOnly = true)
public String someField;
```

but for some reason it doesn't. Functionally, it works, meaning that this field cannot be set when sending requests to a given endpoint, but the field isn't hidden in the POST request docs.

Is this working as intended? Is there a different property to be used?

There are alternative approaches how to hide params e.g. `JsonIgnore`, or the `hidden` param - but the goal is to make a field specifically readonly with `@Schema`, in addition to making it hidden in the POST request docs and visible in the GET/response body docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swagger Core 2.x, `readOnly` has been replaced by [`accessMode`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.2.8/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#accessMode--):

```java
@Schema(accessMode = AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
public String someField;
```